# Кнопка для скачки файла

Tags: javascript, html

Как сделать поле,для скачивания файла?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

если надо скачать файл с сервера, это делается так:

```
<a href="%file_URL%">download</a>
```

Если нужно именно поле, оно делается примерно так:

```
<textarea id="file_here"></textarea>
```

файл в него запихивается так:

```
document.getElementById('file_here').innerHTML = %file_content%
```

конечно, вывод содержимого в innerHTML может быть нормально произведен не для всех данных, а только для текста. поэтому можно сделать не поле, а ссылку или кнопку, по клику на которую будет вызываться функция, загружающая файл, например, такая (модераторы, не бейте, я в упор не помню, где эту функцию нашел, но давно использую):

```
/**
* Инициирует загрузку файла
* @param {string} filename - имя загружаемого файла
* @param {string} data - данные в файле
*/
function downloadFile(filename, data) {
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.style = "display: none";  
    var blob = new Blob([data], {type: "application/octet-stream"});
    var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    a.href = url;
    a.download = filename;
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
window.setTimeout(() => {
    document.body.removeChild(a);
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url); 
    }, 2000);
}
```

Разумеется, данные (%file_content% для textarea и data для функции downloadFile должны быть сгенерированы заранее, например, яваскриптом)

Answer (score 1):

Файл должен находиться на том же домене.

```
<a href="smth.pdf" download>Download</a>
```